# Android View Rotation Animation and Set Rotation not working as intended

Tags: java, android, animation, view, rotation

I am trying to rotate a view 90 degrees, but every time this method is called the view instead jumps forward 90 degrees, then rotates an additional 90 degrees.

I've tried playing with the numbers without success. There seems to be something about how this code works that I do not understand.

Can someone please explain what's currently happening, and what needs to change to get the intended result?

```
public void RotatePoint(float toDegrees) {
    final RotateAnimation rotate =
        new RotateAnimation(pt.getRotation(), pt.getRotation() + toDegrees,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(1000);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    pt.startAnimation(rotate);
    pt.setRotation(pt.getRotation()+toDegrees);
    if (pt.getRotation() == 360) {
        pt.setRotation(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Corrected the following line
    pt.setRotation(pt.getRotation()+toDegrees);
It used to read +90 instead of +toDegrees, 
In this case is may be important that toDegrees is always set to 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take global variables- float rotation = 0,fromRotation=0;

and on Onclick

```
            fromRotation=rotation;
            rotation = rotation + 90;
            RotatePoint(rotation);
```

and RotatePoint(float toDegrees)

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(fromRotation, toDegrees,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(1000);


    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    pt.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: This is a partial solution. In my app I do validation to see what direction the point is facing however with this the rotation constantly increases forever. I added the If(rotation==360){rotation=0;} back in and this works after the first rotation but on the first rotation of each point it still moves randomly. I believe this is because each point starts with a Random rotation (0, 90, 180, or 270) It seems the points are given a random rotation (visually) but that rotation is somehow different from the rotation stored in its variables. Also Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: instead change rotation and fromRotation when

Comment: if(fromRotation==270){fromRotation=0;rotation=0;}

Comment: fromRotation value will give you the intial position of point before rotation and Rotation will give you the value after rotation

Comment: Okay Thanks, So I made the suggested change and that works OK If I get rid of the random starting rotations except for one issue. I am rotating these points inside of a table layout, so there are multiple. If I rotate one point from 0 to 270, everything works. but then If I go to a different point and Rotate it, It will rotate as if it had started at 270. This happens for in every scenario. The Rotation and fromRotation values carry over to different objects. any ideas on that?

Comment: you can take array to store values for each object i guess

Comment: My mistake. I believe Its because I set the variables to static. I appreciate all the help you've given. Thank you